# Spring taking long time to return cached instance of singleton bean - transactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations, transactionmanager

All API call are taking long time to respond because, spring is taking long time to return  cached instance of singleton bean - transactionManager. Please see log, this behaviour is consistent for each request.

2

```
014-09-24 08:09:02,239 DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing GET request for [/emsp/locations]
2014-09-24 08:09:02,239 DEBUG annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /locations
2014-09-24 08:09:02,239 DEBUG annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/locations]
2014-09-24 08:09:02,239 DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/emsp/locations] is: -1
2014-09-24 08:09:02,240 DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
2014-09-24 08:09:02,241 DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'endpointLookupService'
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'txManager'  
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.***.emsp.service.impl.EndpointLookupServiceImpl.getEndpointLocations]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] orphanRemovals=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] collectionQueuedOps=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=[] updates=[] deletions=[] orphanRemovals=[] collectionCreations=[] collectionRemovals=[] collectionUpdates=[] collectionQueuedOps=[] unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtaining JDBC connection
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG resourcepool.BasicResourcePool - trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@7cfea9ab [managed: 1, unused: 0, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@6a4d7764)
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG internal.LogicalConnectionImpl - Obtained JDBC connection
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG spi.AbstractTransactionImpl - begin
2014-09-24 08:09:07,408 DEBUG jdbc.JdbcTransaction - initial autocommit status: true
2014-09-24 08:09:07,408 DEBUG jdbc.JdbcTransaction - disabling autocommit
2014-09-24 08:09:07,408 DEBUG hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@3c0b2e6e]
2014-09-24 08:09:07,408 INFO  impl.EndpointLookupServiceImpl - EndpointLookupServiceImpl::getEndpointLocations - called (Custom log - after this is almost instantaneous)
```

If you see these two lines specifically in the above line - there is a 5sec delay - this keeps increasing after a while but comes down once tomcat is restarted.

```
2014-09-24 08:09:02,241 DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'endpointLookupService'
2014-09-24 08:09:07,407 DEBUG support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'txManager'
```

My spring config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.****.emsp" />
    <!-- Transaction Manager Declaration -->
    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/emsp" />
        <property name="user" value="***" />
        <property name="password" value="***" />
        <!-- C3P0 properties -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="300" />
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="3000" />
        <!--property name="testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true" /> <property 
            name="preferredTestQuery" value="select 1;" / -->
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.****.emsp.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                hibernate.show_sql=false
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And i'm using `@Transactional` annotation for my service APIs involving DB transaction.

Please suggest how to go about debugging this. Also let me know if any another info is required.

Request Handling code:

```
@Service
public class EndpointLookupServiceImpl implements EndpointLookupService {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(EndpointLookupServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    EndpointLocationDaoImpl endpointLoctionDao;
    @Autowired
    SsidDaoImpl ssidDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public EndpointLocationsResp getEndpointLocations(
            String xJwtAssertionHeader, Map<String, List<String>> reqParams) {
        logger.info("EndpointLookupServiceImpl::getEndpointLocations - called with xJwtAssertionHeader:"
                + xJwtAssertionHeader + " reqParams:" + reqParams);

        .....
    }
}
```

Using spring integration as controller for invoking the service:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="endpointLocById"
        request-channel="endpointLocByIdIn"
        supported-methods="GET"
        path="/locations/{locationId}"
        mapped-request-headers="*"
        payload-expression="#pathVariables.locationId" >
    </int-http:inbound-gateway> 
    <int:channel id="endpointLocByIdIn"/>   
    <int:service-activator input-channel="endpointLocByIdIn" expression="@endpointLookupService.getEndpointLocationByLocationId(headers['x-jwt-assertion'], payload)" output-channel="out" />
```

Comment: Please add the request handling code. You aren't creating a new instance of the context each time you need beans do you?

Comment: @M.Deinum No i am not creating a new instance of the context each time. I'm adding the request handling code to the orginal message itself please take a look. Looking forward for your response.

Comment: That is the service not the controller/handler I'm interested in. Also Your service should probably depend on interfaces `EndpointLocationDao` instead of concrete implementations like `EndpointLocationDaoImpl`

Comment: @M.Deinum I am using spring integration to invoke my service. Added this as well to the original post. EndpointLocationDao instead of EndpointLocationDaoImpl is something i am planning to change as well.

Comment: Ah ok. Gets more interesting :). Looks like there is something blocking the processing. You aren't messing around with connections or hibernate sessions yourself? It looks like some depletation or blocking based on the connection pool, can your MySQL instance handle that many connections?

Comment: @M.Deinum Yeah, not sure why it takes spring's DefaultListableBeanFactory so much time to return a cached instance. Once i get txManager instance however everything else is fast as expected. I'm letting hibernate handle sessions using '@'Transaction annotation. Tuned mysql to set global max_connections = 250; and was able to reproduce this behaviour by removing c3p0 and using springs jdbc datasource. Been struggling with this issue for quite sometime now.

Comment: Which makes me believe there is something fishy with the hibernate access you are doing (or maybe are working with a Connection). You aren't using openSession for instance or accessing a sql connection directly?

Comment: When using the Spring Datasource you might want to enable debug logging for it to see where a connection gets created. It isn't a real connection pool so it should open/close connections for each transaction/call to `getConnection` on the `DataSource`.

Comment: Did you have any luck finding out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take thread dumps just before and after you see the blocking to see what your main thread is doing, Spring loads beans in a single thread, so you should be able to see where it is stuck and debug that even more.